# upload log file to sharepoint online - dummy

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have done a few hours of searching in Google I found this method to upload a file to SharePoint online as a tenant rather that the administrator.

I can authenticate and it seems to me would work however the $File is giving me error.

Could someone very kindly point me to the right direction what I am doing wrong?
I have very little Power shell experience therefore any comments are most welcome.

```
#Specify tenant admin and site URL
$User = "email"
$SiteURL = "https://website.sharepoint.com/andras-test/"
$FilePath = "c:\test\lista.txt"
$DocLibName = "Documents"

#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site - required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString

#Bind to site collection
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

#Retrieve list
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocLibName)
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Function to Upload File
function UploadFile($SiteURL, $DocLibName, $FilePath)
{
#Get the Web & Lists to upload the file
#$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
#$List = $Web.GetFolder($DocLibName)

#Get the Files collection
$Files = $List.Files

#Get File Name from Path
$FileName = $FilePath.Substring($FilePath.LastIndexOf("\")+1)

#delete the File from library, if already exist!
#if($Files.Item($DocLibName +"/" + $FileName))
#{
#$Files.delete($DocLibName +"/" + $FileName)
#}

#Get the File
$File= Get-ChildItem $FilePath

#Add File to the collection
$Files.Add($DocLibName +"/" + $FileName,$File.OpenRead(),$false)

#Dispose the objects
#$web.Dispose()
 $context.Dispose()
 }

#call the upload function
#UploadFile "http://sharepoint.company.com" "Monthly Reports" "D:\Reports\LargeLists.txt"
UploadFile $SiteURL $DocLibName "c:\test\lista.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script, i tested and it works.

All you need to run this script is an O365 tenant, the SharePoint client components SDK installed on the machine running the script - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585 and to update the **$User**, **$SiteURL**, **$DocLibName** (name of the destination Document library) and **$Folder** (path to the local folder containing the files to upload) variables. When the script is executed it will prompt for the **password of the user specific in the $User** variable.

```
#Specify tenant admin and site URL
$User = "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site"
$Folder = "C:\FilesToUpload"
$DocLibName = "DocLib"

#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site - required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString

#Bind to site collection
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

#Retrieve list
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocLibName)
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Upload file
Foreach ($File in (dir $Folder))
{
$FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
$FileCreationInfo.URL = $File
$Upload = $List.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
$Context.Load($Upload)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

http://blogs.technet.com/b/fromthefield/archive/2014/02/19/office365-script-to-upload-files-to-a-document-library-using-csom.aspx

Comment: Sarwar Thanks for your input it did work. I was hoping that I can specify the file that I want to upload instead of loading up the whole folder. However, for now I can just delete everything else from that folder to get some result:)